# Publish and subscribe to dBus events with Eclipse EventAdmin?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, dbus

D-Bus on Linux and the EventAdmin in Eclipse both offer a publish/subscribe model. I want to link the two, so I can publish an event to the EventAdmin in Eclipse and it publishes that event to D-Bus and vice versa. A module in Eclipse listens to selected D-Bus events and publishes them to the EventAdmin.
I'm clear how to publish/subscribe to EventAdmin events, but I'm short of Java code that does the d-bus publishing and subscribing. What libraries do I need and where could I find some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best example of dbus-java subscription that I've found:
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2009-October/011879.html